# Failed "Dictionary.subscript.getter" all within same dispatchQueue

Tags: ios, swift, gcdwebserver

I have a handful of production crashes on iOS that look like this:

```
Crashed: com.superdupertango.Server.CallbackRunQueue
0  SDTServer                      0x102b78ed0 specialized Dictionary.subscript.getter + 4378562256 (<compiler-generated>:4378562256)
1  SDTServer                      0x102a22fec closure #1 in Server.processError(_:) + 4377161708 (<compiler-generated>:4377161708)
2  SDTServer                      0x10257ce90 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4372287120 (<compiler-generated>:4372287120)
```

This is the offending code (all code in this area is Swift5):

```
    private let callbackRunQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.superdupertango.Server.CallbackRunQueue", qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated, target: nil)
    var bodyCompletionBlocks: [String: ((Data?, Error?, String) -> Void)] = [:]

...

    private init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.processError(_:)), name: Notification.Name.SDTServerWriteFailed, object: nil)
    }

...

    @objc private func processError(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo, let requestId = userInfo["requestId"] as? String else {
            return
        }
        self.callbackRunQueue.async {
            DLog("Server.processError (\(requestId)): Got Error for request. Shutting down request.")
            guard let bodyCompletionBlock = self.bodyCompletionBlocks[requestId] else {
                DLog("Server.processError (\(requestId)): Failed getting body completion block. Returning")
                return
            }
            bodyCompletionBlock(Data(), nil, requestId)
            self.bodyCompletionBlocks.removeValue(forKey: requestId)
            self.initialCompletionBlocks.removeValue(forKey: requestId)
        }
    }
```

Note that the `callbackRunQueue` is a serial queue.

The only dictionary value that's being retrieved inside the `callbackRunQueue` is the `self.bodyCompletionBlocks`:

```
            guard let bodyCompletionBlock = self.bodyCompletionBlocks[requestId] else {
```

I've found a few references to this error, but they all say that this may be a multi-thread access issue.

However, in my code, there are only 3 places where there is access to `self.bodyCompletionBlocks`, and they are all within `callbackRunQueue.async` or `callbackRunQueue.sync` blocks.  Also note that some of this code is running inside threads within GCDWebServer, but as I mentioned, I'm always ensuring the code runs in my `callbackRunQueue` queue, so I don't think this is GCDWebServer related.

I thought that enclosing thread sensitive code inside a serial queue's async or sync blocks would protect against multi-thread access problems like this.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that in the crashing cases `processError` is called *before* the block was added in `bodyCompletionBlocks`? Can you share the code that registers the completion blocks?